# Is there a working Oauth2 example implementation of Dropwizard and Keycloak?

Tags: dropwizard, keycloak

I would like to see a working example of Dropwizard and Keycloak (OAuth2).

I would like to see how to organize an authentication and authorization process using Jetty and the Adapters provided by Keycloak. Is there an example somewhere?

I have read many supposed tutorials, but they are either missing the concrete implementation of the classes, or are using basic authentication.

Comment: Hi @Pampa did you end up finding a good example for this?

Comment: Hi @emraldinho, unfortunately I did not find anything and in the meanwhile I stopped to work with Dropwizard, so I have not had other opportunities to try